# ¿Por qué no puedo convertir la hora al formato de 24 horas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Estoy intentando convertir la fecha y hora en un formato en el que SQL server me acepte dicho formato; mi servidor tiene la hora configurada en formato 12 horas y no la puedo cambiar, por ese motivo al obtener la hora actual me la arroja en un formato 12 horas (AM. P.M).
Cuando intento almacenar esta hora me arroja una excepción según lo que lei en internet no puedo almacenarlo en este formato, tiene que ser 24 horas. (Si me equivoco por favor corregirme)

No entiendo por qué no me convierte la hora en en formato de 24 horas

```csharp
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] Inventory inventory)
        {
            var x = DateTime.Now;
            x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
            db.Add(inventory);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Registro exitoso!");
            // return CreatedAtRoute("GetInventory", new { id = inventory.inventory_id, }, inventory);
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En que formato tienes en tu equipo local ? la sentencia `DateTime.Now`  toma o captura la hora de tu equipo local.

Comment: @RodrigoTorrico esta en formtado 12 horas,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta agregando el siguiente formato:

```
 x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Otra alternativa es agregando [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0):

```
 x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```